# Mapping a sphere with a grid of Polygons

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm currently trying to map a sphere with squares using d3.js and GeoJon. I've found a script which generate a grid using MultiPolygon : https://jsfiddle.net/94dhdmnw/

```
{
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [{
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'MultiPolygon',
            coordinates: [coordinates]
        }
    }]
}
```

Nonetheless, I need an id for each square of my grid. That's why I want to map my sphere using Polygons instead of MultiPolygons. Thus, I've adapted the script in order to get a Polygon mapping : https://jsfiddle.net/et3s6p33/
Yet, when I map my sphere using the file obtained through the Polygon script, I have only half of my sphere which is mapped - not even with the right squares' size.

Sphere with MultiPolygon mapping :
[image: Sphere with MultiPolygon mapping]

Sphere with Polygon mapping :
[image: Sphere with Polygon mapping]

Any ideas why?

I am using this script to map my sphere : http://jsfiddle.net/6n230b3w

Edit : Or maybe there is a way to set a property for each square of my MultiPolygon?